# is there any way to pass class object generically to the method

Tags: c#, class, generics

I have class object like this as below

```
public class Version
{

    [JsonIgnore]
    public  string ClassName = "Version";

    [JsonIgnore]
    public string Name { get; set; } = "Version 1";
    .......
    .......
}
```

I am passing this class object to the method like as below

```
class EpJSON
{
    public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>> model = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>>();

    public void Add(dynamic v)
    {
        if (model.ContainsKey(v.ClassName))
        {
            if (model[v.ClassName].ContainsKey(v.Name))
            {
                model[v.ClassName][v.Name] = v;
            }
            else
            {
                model[v.ClassName].Add(v.Name, v);
            }

        }
        else
        {
            Dictionary<string, object> obj = new Dictionary<string, object>() { { v.Name, v } };
            model.Add(v.ClassName, obj);
        }

    }

    public void Save(string path)
    {
        using (StreamWriter file = File.CreateText(path))
        {
            JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
            serializer.Serialize(file, model);
        }
    }

}
```

I am calling the Add method like as below

```
var model = new EpJSON();
var ver1 = new Version() { VersionIdentifier = "9.2" };
model.Add(ver1);
var ver2 = new Version() { Name = "V2", VersionIdentifier = "9.3" };
model.Add(ver2);
model.Save(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "test.json"));
```

I would like to get the suggestion from you guys is there any generic way to pass the `Version` object to method `Add` and I can be able to pass other object that is exactly same like as this object with extra fields

please let me know if you need more information

updated code

```
public void Add([dynamicObj] v)
{
    if (model.ContainsKey([dynamicObj].ClassName))
    {
        if (model[[dynamicObj].ClassName].ContainsKey([dynamicObj].Name))
        {
            model[[dynamicObj].ClassName][[dynamicObj].Name] = v;
        }
       ......
    }
    ......
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by generic way to pass the version object? you are already passing it from what i can see

Comment: @Steve i am looking is there any way to pass dynamically or generic way to pass the version object .. and i might need pass some other class as well not only version  in future

Comment: you need to provide some examples for what you want to achieve. do those classes share the same base class or interface? if not then what can you achieve by doing the generic way instead of just accept `Add(object o)`? If they share a base class or interface why not just use that as the parameter?

Comment: @Steve they won't share the same base class and i updated the question and added some examples of code that i am looking for ... many thanks for your support

Comment: Whats dynamicObj.Name? is it some property on the dynamicObj? if so then you are looking for a second parameter instead of generic method. Generic can only pass `type` which only contains information from the assembly level not from run time.

Comment: `dynamicObj` is object of another class (i.e) i can be able to pass another class as well.

Comment: lets get the terminology right. If you want to pass an object then you are looking for a second parameter. If you are looking to pass the type(class definition) then generic will work.

Comment: The language version tags should only be used if your question pertains to specific features in those versions of the language.  That isn't the case here.  Read the tag descriptions.

Comment: You could use an ExpandoObject instead, or, pass JSON and deserialize to that class.

Comment: @Steve i am looking to pass the type to the method in generic way .. could you please point me in right direction thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By *generic* I'm not exactly sure what you mean. If you want to dynamically invoke the Add method of your `EpJson` class, you can use the [GetMethod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getmethod?view=netframework-4.8) function of the Type class. Here's an example using `List<string>`, but it surely works with any type:

```cs
var myList = new List<string>();
var addMethod = myList.GetType().GetMethod(nameof(myList.Add));
addMethod.Invoke(myList, new object[] { "hello" });

Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", myList)); // produces "hello"
```

**EDIT:** Okay I think I get what you mean. You have to use polymorphism to achieve this. Let's say you want to pass objects which has `ClassName` and `Name` properties. Then you could define an interface like:

```cs
public interface IObjectWithRequiredProperties
{
    string ClassName { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then make your `Version` class an implementor of this interface by changing the class definition to

```cs
public class Version : IObjectWithRequiredProperties
...
```

This will *force* the class to contain those properties you define on the interface. And now comes the fun part, you have to make your `Add` method generic by changing it to

```cs
public void Add<TGeneric>(TGeneric v) where TGeneric: IObjectWithRequiredProperties
```

Now you can be sure that whatever is passed to the `Add` method, it will have all the properties that `IObjectWithRequiredProperties` has. Naturally you have to change the underlying dictionary to your interface's type. This is called a [generic type constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters).

Comment: Hi i am looking for generic way to pass that version object to the add method .. i can be able to pass other object in future that is having same kind of properties

Comment: what are the changes that i need to make to the dictionary to make sure it is relates to the interface

Comment: What is your dictionary's type currently? Basically you need to replace Version with IObjectWithRequiredProperties or whatever your interface's name will be.

Comment: I have added my complete class related to Add method.. could you please see the updated code in question .. could you please direct me is there any changes need to do for epjson class

Answer (score 0):

I would still suggest the interface way but if you absolutely want to do what you described then `dynamic` keyword or reflection will do

```
    public void Add(dynamic v)
    {
        Type type = v.GetType();

        bool hasClassNameProperty = type.GetProperty("ClassName") != null;
        if (hasClassNameProperty)
        {
            string className = v.ClassName;
        }

        bool hasNameProperty = type.GetProperty("Name") != null;
        if (hasNameProperty)
        {
            string name = v.Name;
        }
    }

    public void Add2(object o)
    {
        Type type = o.GetType();
        PropertyInfo classNameProperty = type.GetProperty("ClassName");
        if (classNameProperty != null)
        {
            string className = (string)classNameProperty.GetValue(o);
        }

        PropertyInfo nameProperty = type.GetProperty("Name");
        if (nameProperty != null)
        {
            string name = (string)nameProperty.GetValue(o);
        }
    }
```

Comment: many thanks but I think you misunderstood my concept, I am looking to use only one variable in a generic way not with two parameters passing to the method.. I hope you understand.. I modified my updated part and i want to pass single parameter only in generic way

Comment: @EnigmaState what you are trying to achieve is similar to javascript where any object is a dynamic object and is not strong typed. You can do this using reflection or the keyword `dynamic`. but i wouldnt recommend it.

Comment: i tried with dynamic but it looks like it is not working

Comment: @EnigmaState see updated answer. though not recommended. Its a strong code smell.

Comment: I could not able to understand this line `string className = type.Name;` i do have properties of `Version` class like `ClassName` and `name` and both are having values

Comment: @EnigmaState I thought you want the assembly class name. if its a property then just do the same thing as the name property.